# My extension links not showing on custom roles on admin

Tags: magento2, extensions, permissions, user-roles, acl

I have created a custom module. When I have created a demo user and select custom roles for that. My module not showing on the admin side. When I select all the rights it's showing but when I select all/Some of the roles by selection than it's not showing on the admin side.
My menu code is like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../Magento/Backend/etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Example_Abc::elements" title="EWD FAQ" module="Example_Abc"  sortOrder="60"  resource="Example_Abc::elements"/>
        <add id="Example_Abc::faq" title="Manage FAQs" module="Example_Abc" parent="Example_Abc::elements" sortOrder="61" action="example_abc/faq" resource="Example_Abc::faq"/>
        <add id="Example_Abc::category" title="Manage Categories" module="Example_Abc" parent="Example_Abc::elements" sortOrder="62" action="example_bc/category" resource="Example_Abc::category"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

ACL.XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Example_Abc::faqs" title="FAQs">
                    <resource id="Example_Abc::faq" title="FAQs Manager">
                        <resource id="Example_Abc::faq_create" title="Create"/>
                        <resource id="Example_Abc::faq_edit" title="Edit" />
                        <resource id="Example_Abc::faq_delete" title="Delete"/>
                    </resource>
                    <resource id="Example_Abc::category" title="Categories Manager">
                        <resource id="Example_Abc::category_create" title="Create"/>
                        <resource id="Example_Abc::category_edit" title="Edit" />
                        <resource id="Example_Abc::category_delete" title="Delete"/>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Comment: Please share the code of acl.xml?

Comment: @MohitKumarArora Acl file added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing `Example_Abc::elements` with `Example_Abc::faqs` my extension starts on demo user.I have used `faqs` on acl.xml.My menu code is now like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../Magento/Backend/etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Example_Abc::faqs" title="EWD FAQ" module="Example_Abc"  sortOrder="60"  resource="Example_Abc::faqs"/>
        <add id="Example_Abc::faq" title="Manage FAQs" module="Example_Abc" parent="Example_Abc::faqs" sortOrder="61" action="example_abc/faq" resource="Example_Abc::faq"/>
        <add id="Example_Abc::category" title="Manage Categories" module="Example_Abc" parent="Example_Abc::faqs" sortOrder="62" action="example_bc/category" resource="Example_Abc::category"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```